# How to detect a touch of a child sprite

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, parent-child

I know that this may have been asked before, but nothing has exactly what I need. Now imagine this situation, I have a game and in this game there is an SKSpriteNode called Background in the middle of the screen. On that Background Sprite there is a child called Button. How would I detect if a touch was ended on the Button. If somebody could please help me with the code for the TouchesEnded function, as well as maybe explain in further detail what is happening. Thank you, swift would be ideal, but I guess I can read Objective-C if I need to.

**ADDED INFO**

Here are my two sprites:

```
let buttonBackground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Button Background.png") //The parent node of button
let soundOn = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sound On.png") //The button being pressed, which is a child of buttonBackground
```

Here is my touchesEnded function:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    // Called when a touch begins

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let nodeAtTouch = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        let touchedSprite = nodeAtTouch as! SKSpriteNode

        if touchedSprite == button {
            print("YES")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a touch ends, get the node from that point

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let something = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        let skNode = something as! SKSpriteNode
        //Do something with skNode
    }
}
```

Comment: skNode is the SKSpriteNode that you retrieved from touching. Please show some code of how your collision works. If you are unfamiliar with this, check out this: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Swift_iOS_8_Sprite_Kit_Collision_Handling_Tutorial

Comment: my bad I meant a statement to show the if of when the skNode is touched

Comment: The skNode is the node that is touched... Whenever a touch occurs skNode is the node that was touched

Comment: oh okay, I understand, but this doesn't work with my code

Comment: Print skNode. Let me know what you get

Comment: I updated it, and for the skNode it prints whenever I click (and it prints properly), but when I click the button that is the child, then nothing prints

Comment: could my problem be that my parent node's anchor point is (0.5,0) and the buttons is (0.5,0.5)

Comment: Thank you I got it when I set the sprites to have UserInteraction it would detect the collisions.

Comment: Glad I could help :)